# How can vim reformat `gq` avoid touching TeX verbatim sections?

Tags: vim, latex, reformat

In a LaTeX file, I have several `verbatim` sections scattered all throughout.

When I want to reformat the whole document, I usually use `gq`. The problem is that this command also gather the contiguous lines of verbatim sections. I don't want `gq` to reformat my verbatim sections!

Before the reformat:

```
This is the
line I want to reformat because is spans on two lines and the
first does not fill to the right.

\begin{verbatim}
$ command1
$ command2
\end{verbatim}
```

After the reformat:

```
This is the line I want to reformat because is spans
on two lines and the first does not fill to the right.

\begin{verbatim} $ command1 $ command2 \end{verbatim}
```

Is there another command for a **smart** TeX reformat in vim?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `gq}` to just reformat the rest of the paragraph. I suspect it is not possible to do what you want without writing/using a script.

[LaTeX Box](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109) does not advertise this feature, but should anyone implement it that script would be a natural home for this functionality.